# Do i need JPA provider (like Hibernate) if i am using EJB?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

i am reading book about EJB 3.l, and they are talking about Enities and EntityManager, but i cant see any Hibernate(or other ORM framework) configuration. Does EJB has its own ORM and JPA support ?

Comment: Please look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952730/how-does-ejb-and-jpa-relate

Comment: `EJB` does not have its own ORM functionality. Need to integrate with an ORM framework like `JPA` or `JDBC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EJB](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/) and [JPA](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/) are two different specifications that are part of the Java EE standard. You can use either of them without using the other.

EDIT: EJB is used within Java EE compliant servers like [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/) (formerly known as JBoss) and [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/). IF you are using one, you always have an implementation of JPA on board.

JPA on the other hand is not bound to such a server and can be used in servlet containers like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and standalone Java SE applications.

Comment: **You can use either of them without using the other.** Can you use EJB only for persistence without JPA or JDBC, or other ORM technologies?

Comment: Yes, you can use EJB without any persistence technologies. However, if you need to persist data to a database, JPA is a natural fit. I would use JDBC without JPA only if the requirements demand it. Otherwise, it feels cumbersome in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

JPA can be used outside the container like with RESTful WS. While EJB resides in containers like WebLogic, Tomcat, etc.

In a way, JPA is a lighter version of EJB. Try googling JPA vs EJB3

Comment: -1 Multiple factual errors: EJB is not used in Tomcat - Tomcat is not Java EE compliant. Webservices have absolutely nothing to do with JPA. JPA is not a version of EJB, not in any way.